# Wake PC on LAN from Raspberry Pi

Tags: openelec

I have been investigating.

I want to wake-on-lan a PC I have on the same LAN as the Raspberry Pi.

Wake on LAN doesn't work over the internet, so, I though to use the Raspberry Pi to wake up my PC. Using a binary would be fine.

I have found some binaries that would do the job, but since I am using OPENELEC on my Raspberry Pi, I can not download them.
Here are some tools I have found:

- **wol**
- **etherwake**
- **wakeonlan**

afaik, any one of those would work. But I can not find the binary, only the sources or download via repository.

*I need the binary to run on my OPENELEC Raspberry Pi. Could someone compile it or share one that would work?*

Thanks!!

I have also found these tools:

[WOL Repeater using Arduino](http://www.finalclap.com/tuto/arduino-wake-on-lan-repeater-80/)

[Raspberry Pi as WOL Forwarder](http://blog.depicus.com/using-a-raspberry-pi-as-a-wake-on-lan-forwarder/)

Answer (score 5):

Finally i could solve it. a simply python script to send a magic packet.

replace the QQ on the last line with your target pc's MAC address. with lowercase.
just exec it, and voilà...

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import socket

s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_BROADCAST, 1)
s.sendto('\xff'*6+'\xQQ\xQQ\xQQ\xQQ\xQQ\xQQ'*16, ("255.255.255.255",9))
```